# Trigonometry and triangle proof

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Question:
Prove that in an acute angle triangle ABC:
$$\tan A\tan B +\tan A \tan C + \tan B \tan C \geq 9$$

I have no idea where to even begin this question. Please help me!

Comment: Do you mean $\tan A\tan B+\tan A\tan C + \tan B \tan C\ge 9$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ummm.... I double checked, but the question still says what I wrote. However, it might be a typo. I'll edit the question to the one that you have said. Please help me with that too.

Answer (score 4):

Note that 
$$\tan C=-\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{\tan A\tan B-1}.$$
That means
$$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=\tan A\tan B\tan C,$$
or 
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\tan A\tan B}=1.$$
The given inequality is now obvious.

Comment: How exactly is it obvious?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: In particular $(a+b+c)(1/a+1/b+1/c)\geq 9$.

Comment: I see, never heard of that inequality though. But that's true for any value of a, b, and c?

Comment: for positive numbers, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Answer (score 3):

Since for an acute triangle $ABC$ we have
$$\begin{align}\tan A+\tan B&=(\tan (A+B))\cdot (1-\tan A\tan B)\\&=(\tan(\pi -C))\cdot (1-\tan A\tan B)\\&=(-\tan C)\cdot (1-\tan A\tan B),\end{align}$$
we have$$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=\tan A\tan B\tan C.$$
Hence, we have, by AM-GM inequality,$$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\tan A\tan B\tan C}$$
$$\iff \tan A\tan B\tan C\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\tan A\tan B\tan C}$$
$$\iff \tan A\tan B\tan C\ge 3\sqrt 3.$$
Hence, we have, by AM-GM inequality,
$$\begin{align}\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A&\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\tan^2A\tan^2B\tan^2C}\ge 9.\end{align}$$

Comment: How do you know that $\tan A \tan B \tan C$ is equal to 3?

Comment: @Gummybears: Where? I think I don't write $\tan A\tan B\tan C=3$...

Comment: No sorry. You wrote that cube root of that is equal to 3.

Comment: @Gummybears: Yes, exactly. This is because $\tan A\tan B\tan C\ge 3\sqrt 3$ which I wrote first.

Comment: @mathlove your answer is completely correct. The inequality satisfies all triangles, not just acute triangles. isn't it?

Comment: @user157716: I don't think so because I used AM-GM inequality for which we have to have positive numbers.

Comment: oh yes. Thats right